# An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, bilstm

I'm attempting to build bidirectional LSTM seq2seq model in Keras, however I am running into an issue when passing the output states of the encoder to the input states of the decoder. It looks like that should be possible based on this pull request. Ultimately I want to keep the encoder_output vector for additional downstream tasks.

`The error message:`
172             # Equation 11
--> 173             hidden_state, _, cell_state = self.input_lstm(
174                 X_tilde_t,
175                 initial_state=[hidden_state, cell_state]

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'encoder_input' (type Encoder).

An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=ListWrapper([InputSpec(shape=(256, 128), ndim=2)]); however `cell.state_size` is [128, 128]

````
from typing import Optional

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    Layer,
    LSTM,
    Dense,
    Permute,
    Bidirectional
)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

def check_T(T: int):
    if T < 2:
        raise ValueError(
            f'T must be an integer larger than 1, but got `{T}`'
        )


"""
Notation (according to the paper)
Naming Convention::
    Variable_{time_step}__{sequence_number_of_driving_series}
Variables / HyperParameters:
    T (int): the size (time steps) of the window
    m (int): the number of the encoder hidden states
    p (int): the number of the decoder hidden states
    n (int): the number of features of a single driving series
    X: the n driving (exogenous) series of shape (batch_size, T, n)
    X_tilde: the new input for the encoder, i.e. X̃ = (x̃_1, ..., x̃_t, x̃_T)
    Y: the historical/previous T - 1 predictions, (y_1, y_2, ..., y_Tminus1)
    hidden_state / h: hidden state
    cell_state / s: cell state
    Alpha_t: attention weights of the input attention layer at time t
    Beta_t: attention weights of the temporal attention layer at time t
"""


class InputAttention(Layer):
    T: int

    def __init__(self, T, **kwargs):
        """
        Calculates the encoder attention weight Alpha_t at time t
        Args:
            T (int): the size (time steps) of the window
        """

        super().__init__(name='input_attention', **kwargs)

        self.T = T

        self.W_e = Dense(T)
        self.U_e = Dense(T)
        self.v_e = Dense(1)

    def call(
        self,
        hidden_state,
        cell_state,
        X
    ):
        """
        Args:
            hidden_state: hidden state of shape (batch_size, m) at time t - 1
            cell_state: cell state of shape (batch_size, m) at time t - 1
            X: the n driving (exogenous) series of shape (batch_size, T, n)
        Returns:
            The attention weights (Alpha_t) at time t, i.e.
            (a_t__1, a_t__2, ..., a_t__n)
        """

        n = X.shape[2]

        # [h_t-1; s_t-1]
        hs = K.repeat(
            tf.concat([hidden_state, cell_state], axis=-1),
            # -> (batch_size, m * 2)
            n
        )
        # -> (batch_size, n, m * 2)

        tanh = tf.math.tanh(
            tf.concat([
                self.W_e(hs),
                # -> (batch_size, n, T)

                self.U_e(
                    Permute((2, 1))(X)
                    # -> (batch_size, n, T)
                ),
                # -> (batch_size, n, T)
            ], axis=-1)
            # -> (batch_size, n, T * 2)
        )
        # -> (batch_size, n, T * 2)

        # Equation 8:
        e = self.v_e(tanh)
        # -> (batch_size, n, 1)

        # Equation: 9
        return tf.nn.softmax(
            Permute((2, 1))(e)
            # -> (batch_size, 1, n)
        )
        # -> (batch_size, 1, n)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'T': self.T
        })
        return config


class Encoder(Layer):
    T: int
    m: int

    def __init__(
        self,
        T: int,
        m: int,
        **kwargs
    ):
        """
        Generates the new input X_tilde for encoder
        Args:
            T (int): the size (time steps) of the window
            m (int): the number of the encoder hidden states
        """

        super().__init__(name='encoder_input', **kwargs)

        self.T = T
        self.m = m

        self.input_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(m, return_state=True))
        self.input_attention = InputAttention(T)

    def call(self, X) -> tf.Tensor:
        """
        Args:
            X: the n driving (exogenous) series of shape (batch_size, T, n)
        Returns:
            The encoder hidden state of shape (batch_size, T, m)
        """

        batch_size = K.shape(X)[0]

        hidden_state = tf.zeros((batch_size, self.m))
        cell_state = tf.zeros((batch_size, self.m))

        X_encoded = []

        for t in range(self.T):
            Alpha_t = self.input_attention(hidden_state, cell_state, X)

            # Equation 10
            X_tilde_t = tf.multiply(
                Alpha_t,
                # TODO:
                # make sure it can share the underlying data
                X[:, None, t, :]
            )
            # -> (batch_size, 1, n)

            # Equation 11
            hidden_state, _, cell_state = self.input_lstm(
                X_tilde_t,
                initial_state=[hidden_state, cell_state]
            )

            X_encoded.append(
                hidden_state[:, None, :]
                # -> (batch_size, 1, m)
            )

        return tf.concat(X_encoded, axis=1)
        # -> (batch_size, T, m)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'T': self.T,
            'm': self.m
        })
        return config


class TemporalAttention(Layer):
    m: int

    def __init__(self, m: int, **kwargs):
        """
        Calculates the attention weights::
            Beta_t = (beta_t__1, ..., beta_t__i, ..., beta_t__T) (1 <= i <= T)
        for each encoder hidden state h_t at the time step t
        Args:
            m (int): the number of the encoder hidden states
        """

        super().__init__(name='temporal_attention', **kwargs)

        self.m = m

        self.W_d = Dense(m)
        self.U_d = Dense(m)
        self.v_d = Dense(1)

    def call(
        self,
        hidden_state,
        cell_state,
        X_encoded
    ):
        """
        Args:
            hidden_state: hidden state `d` of shape (batch_size, p)
            cell_state: cell state `s` of shape (batch_size, p)
            X_encoded: the encoder hidden states (batch_size, T, m)
        Returns:
            The attention weights for encoder hidden states (beta_t)
        """

        # Equation 12
        l = self.v_d(
            tf.math.tanh(
                tf.concat([
                    self.W_d(
                        K.repeat(
                            tf.concat([hidden_state, cell_state], axis=-1),
                            # -> (batch_size, p * 2)
                            X_encoded.shape[1]
                        )
                        # -> (batch_size, T, p * 2)
                    ),
                    # -> (batch_size, T, m)
                    self.U_d(X_encoded)
                ], axis=-1)
                # -> (batch_size, T, m * 2)
            )
            # -> (batch_size, T, m)
        )
        # -> (batch_size, T, 1)

        # Equation 13
        return tf.nn.softmax(l, axis=1)
        # -> (batch_size, T, 1)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'm': self.m
        })
        return config


class Decoder(Layer):
    T: int
    m: int
    p: int
    y_dim: int

    def __init__(
        self,
        T: int,
        m: int,
        p: int,
        y_dim: int,
        **kwargs
    ):
        """
        Calculates y_hat_T
        Args:
            T (int): the size (time steps) of the window
            m (int): the number of the encoder hidden states
            p (int): the number of the decoder hidden states
            y_dim (int): prediction dimentionality
        """

        super().__init__(name='decoder', **kwargs)

        self.T = T
        self.m = m
        self.p = p
        self.y_dim = y_dim

        self.temp_attention = TemporalAttention(m)
        self.dense = Dense(1)
        self.decoder_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(p, return_state=True))

        self.Wb = Dense(p)
        self.vb = Dense(y_dim)

    def call(self, Y, X_encoded) -> tf.Tensor:
        """
        Args:
            Y: prediction data of shape (batch_size, T - 1, y_dim) from time 1 to time T - 1. See Figure 1(b) in the paper
            X_encoded: encoder hidden states of shape (batch_size, T, m)
        Returns:
            y_hat_T: the prediction of shape (batch_size, y_dim)
        """

        batch_size = K.shape(X_encoded)[0]
        hidden_state = tf.zeros((batch_size, self.p))
        cell_state = tf.zeros((batch_size, self.p))

        # c in the paper
        context_vector = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1, self.m))
        # -> (batch_size, 1, m)

        for t in range(self.T - 1):
            Beta_t = self.temp_attention(
                hidden_state,
                cell_state,
                X_encoded
            )
            # -> (batch_size, T, 1)

            # Equation 14
            context_vector = tf.matmul(
                Beta_t, X_encoded, transpose_a=True
            )
            # -> (batch_size, 1, m)

            # Equation 15
            y_tilde = self.dense(
                tf.concat([Y[:, None, t, :], context_vector], axis=-1)
                # -> (batch_size, 1, y_dim + m)
            )
            # -> (batch_size, 1, 1)

            # Equation 16
            hidden_state, _, cell_state = self.decoder_lstm(
                y_tilde,
                initial_state=[hidden_state, cell_state]
            )
            # -> (batch_size, p)

        concatenated = tf.concat(
            [hidden_state[:, None, :], context_vector], axis=-1
        )
        # -> (batch_size, 1, m + p)

        # Equation 22
        y_hat_T = self.vb(
            self.Wb(concatenated)
            # -> (batch_size, 1, p)
        )
        # -> (batch_size, 1, y_dim)

        return tf.squeeze(y_hat_T, axis=1)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config().copy()
        config.update({
            'T': self.T,
            'm': self.m,
            'p': self.p,
            'y_dim': self.y_dim
        })
        return config


class DARNN(Model):
    def __init__(
        self,
        T: int,
        m: int,
        p: Optional[int] = None,
        y_dim: int = 1
    ):
        """
        Args:
            T (int): the size (time steps) of the window
            m (int): the number of the encoder hidden states
            p (:obj:`int`, optional): the number of the decoder hidden states. Defaults to `m`
            y_dim (:obj:`int`, optional): prediction dimentionality. Defaults to `1`
        Model Args:
            inputs: the concatenation of
            - n driving series (x_1, x_2, ..., x_T) and
            - the previous (historical) T - 1 predictions (y_1, y_2, ..., y_Tminus1, zero)
        `inputs` Explanation::
            inputs_t = (x_t__1, x_t__2, ..., x_t__n, y_t__1, y_t__2, ..., y_t__d)
            where
            - d is the prediction dimention
            - y_T__i = 0, 1 <= i <= d.
            Actually, the model will not use the value of y_T
        Usage::
            model = DARNN(10, 64, 64)
            y_hat = model(inputs)
        """

        super().__init__(name='DARNN')

        check_T(T)

        self.T = T
        self.m = m
        self.p = p or m
        self.y_dim = y_dim

        self.encoder = Encoder(T, m)
        self.decoder = Decoder(T, m, self.p, y_dim=y_dim)

    # Equation 1
    def call(self, inputs):
        X = inputs[:, :, :-self.y_dim]
        # -> (batch_size, T, n)

        # Y's window size is one less than X's
        # so, abandon `y_T`

        # By doing this, there are some benefits which makes it pretty easy to
        # process datasets
        Y = inputs[:, :, -self.y_dim:]
        # -> (batch_size, T - 1, y_dim)

        X_encoded = self.encoder(X)

        y_hat_T = self.decoder(Y, X_encoded)
        # -> (batch_size, y_dim)

        return y_hat_T

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            'T': self.T,
            'm': self.m,
            'p': self.p,
            'y_dim': self.y_dim
        }```


Any help/advice/direction is greatly appreciated!
````